# DDL in Access - AUTOINCREMENT - may I use sql instead of number in argument?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I have a query in Access:

```
CREATE TABLE [t_Clusters_PassportsMicrofilm(fromDuplication)]    
(
[CLUSTER_ID] AUTOINCREMENT (92561,1),    
[NAME1_ID] TEXT(50),    
[NAME2_ID] TEXT(50),    
[NAME3_ID] TEXT(50),    
[NAME4_ID] TEXT(50),    
[NAME5_ID] TEXT(50))
```

but my infrastructure must be dynamic - "92561" as the argument value will probably change. I want to use an SQL statement instead of number for its value.

SQL statement like this:

```
MaxOfID_Research
FROM [t_Clusters_ResearchPassportsMicrofilms(afterDuplication)_union]
```

Does somebody know how I can make it work?